# Gitlab-CI: Trigger build only when specific folders are updated

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am working on improving our current build system for a very large .Net project. To put it in context - this project has 178 Visual Studio Solutions and in excess of 800 csproj files.

We are currently using TeamCity but with the number of teams we have it has become a huge mess and is becoming very difficult to maintain. At some point we migrated to Gitlab (before I arrived) and I am trying to get a workable solution using Gitlab-CI.

I have managed to build, Test, and Package, every component using Gitlab-CI but it is not pretty since everything is being done in 1 Job. We decided to do it like this for now since it is very difficult (and slow) to manage all the artifacts in Gitlab-CI if we build the individual components. But I'll leave that for another SO question... ;-)

My question today is how can I configure my .gitlab-ci.yml file to only execute a job IF there were changes to that specific folder?

Consider this (simplified) directory tree:

```
.
├── Build
├── Config
├── Core
├── Database
├── Services
└── Websites
```

If changes are merged in to master that affect Core or Config, then the entire tree should be built and tested since EVERYTHING depends on these components.
However, if a changes is made to Services there is no need to build and test anything other than Services.

Similarly, and maybe this is getting too complex, if Database changes then only build Database and Services.

Comment: Do you use dedicated branches for the components?

Comment: @mgansler I assume you mean git branches? At this stage no - everything is sitting in 1 repository. Usually a team will fork off the main repo and then merge their changes back in later.

Comment: yes, I meant git branches. If you would introduce a dedicated branch for each component you could use gitlab-ci's `only`: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except

Comment: @mgansler - yes that could work. We are using only at the moment to determine when to execute specific jobs. For example - deploy only happens for tags. I'll have to give it some thought though - it may take a while to move over to a process like that. The problem of course is that some changes may touch "Services" and "Core" so having a branch per folder is quite challenging

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon your question.

This is just and idea but inside your build script you could compare `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h Database` to `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h` and only rebuild if this differs.

`git log -n 1` will show you some information about the last commit for your repo or a specific directory / file.

```
commit <full sha hash of current commit>
Author: Author Name <user@domain.tld>
Date:   Fri Mar 10 11:08:42 2017 +0100

    commit message
```

while `--pretty=format:%h` will just output the shortened hash

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h
1234567

git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h Database
7654321
```